# How to remove Firefox from update manager?

Tags: firefox, update-manager

I uninstalled Firefox some days ago, because I use another browser. It appeared yesterday as an important security update. I can uncheck every package associated with it, and install the remaining updates, but it just keeps showing up, and it's a little annoying.

How can I disable it, so it won't show up again in the update manager, unless I chose to reinstall it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is getting pulled in by some other package. You would need to check in synaptic (under package properties) for what depends on/recommends firefox and remove it (unless it is important). BTW having firefox installed won't get in your way ;).

Comment: The language packages were the guilty ones. It's true, Firefox won't get in my way, but I really don't use Firefox on this particular computer and my ISP sucks, so I just removed all the software I'm not using (less packages to download on each update). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've hit this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/800857

Should be fixed by now.

Answer (score 3):

From the command line <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, what does the following buy you?

```
sudo apt-get install deborphan debfoster 
sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox
sudo apt-get clean
```

The later will clean the /var directory.

```
sudo debfoster
```

The above command will show files and libraries still left after the `apt-get remove --purge`.  If you don't recognize a library, keep it.  Later on, `deborphan` will give you a list of 'orphaned' libraries that are hanging with no use, and are safe to nuke.

If you make a mistake with debfoster, type 'u' and will ask you again if you want to keep it. When you are thru with it, invoke deborphan.

```
sudo deborphan
```

The above command will give a list of libraries that are hanging just taking space.  To get rid of them, use the following command:

```
sudo deborphan | xargs apt-get -y remove purge
sudo apt-get clean
```