# Update Manager shows Firefox when already installed

Tags: firefox, update-manager

I'm very very new to the Linux and Ubuntu world. The Update Manager is showing three important (security) updates:

1. Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla
2. English language pack for Firefox
3. Spanish language pack for Firefox

I have Firefox already installed, it came with my Ubuntu installation, and in Spanish! What I'm supposed to do?

There's a [similar question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50141/how-to-remove-firefox-from-update-manager) (2011) which says that it's a bug, but we're in 2014 and I'm still having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to accept all updates of all software of your preference specially if you already did your homework and checked in any-giving forum that the most current updates are safe to run. In this case if you are running Firefox like you said you are and you use it and in the Spanish version because it is your native language than you should be find. Another thing to keep in mind that Depending on the version of ubuntu that you are running 12.04, 13.10 you must know that that by to-date there has been many security updates and version released since the time of the release of the Ubuntu version that you installed. I personally love to stay up to date with all my software is just good practice as I mentioned before especially if it involves security updates.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have an older version of firefox installed.  The Update Manager will install the newest version.  This is an excellent feature that it updates all your apps all at once.